# Joomla Assign Template

Tags: templates, joomla, menu, default

I'm using Joomla 2.5.7 and trying to assign a few menu items to a different template.

When I open, for example, the Atomic template that comes with Joomla and assign it to a particular menu item, it does not show on the site. It continues to show my default template instead.

Has anyone had this problem and if so, know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the link given below to assign the different template to specific menu item. But you cannot assign the default template to individual pages.

[How do you assign a template to a specific page?](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_assign_a_template_to_a_specific_page%3f)